# Need an alternative for iframes for jQuery ui tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-tabs

I have a Spring based web app working with with jQuery Tabs.

I bulid up a data string (containg specific) and append to a URL

```
var hrefData = "?" + item1 + "&" + item2 + "&" + item3;
var href = "myURL";
href = href + hrefData;
```

basically I use the following to load the URL into my jQuery based tab:

```
$( ui.panel ).append( '<iframe frameborder="0" style="border:0px" src="'+href+'" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>');
```

My servlet controller receives this URL and I get the paramaters from the string and process, returning the resulting data & page, which is displayed within the iframe stated above.

I dont want to use iframe for this. Can someone suggest an alternative solution or provide an example, to perhaps write the HTML to the tab panel instead, or something similar.

Thanks

---

I have also tried this:

```
            $.get(href, function(data){
                alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
                $('ui.panel').append(data); // also tried .load(data);
            });
```

But this doesn't work.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

How about using jQuery load()?

```
$('ui.panel').load(href);
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this and it didn't work. Nothing is loaded

Comment: Are you trying to access content on a different domain? Note the  warning in the jQuery doc, "most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol." Here is a jsFiddle with it working: http://jsfiddle.net/PEp6h/3/

Answer (score 1):

How about using client side templates (handlebars.js, but many other very good alternatives).

The reply will be a simple JSON object that will be mapped into the client side template (instead of, say, a JSP page).